# Images direction changed because FlowDirection is set to RightToLeft

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF UserControl in which I've defined `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`

I've noticed that the direction of all button images in the toolbar has changed because of that.

How can I avoid that without setting `FlowDirection="LeftToRight"` for each button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `declare default Style in your resource for button` so that it gets applied to all button by default in your UserControl. This way you don't have to go each button and set its property manually.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

It won't work for button since buttons in toolbar apply style identified by `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey`. So add you need to have two styles and simply set second style to be based on first button. This is how you will do that:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}" TargetType="Button"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for buttons that are inside the toolbar

Comment: Please see the edit. It will work for Toolbar buttons as well. Also do upvote/accept the answer if it works for you.